# Getting Runtime error when copying range items from one sheet to a newly created worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I can't seem to copy and paste contents from one worksheet to another worksheet - I get a runtime error which I don't understand why... please enlighten me..

here is the code:

```
Dim cell As String

 For i = 2 To cat_lastRow
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    cell = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, cat_col).Value
    Sheets("skeleton").Range("A1:S21").Copy

    If Not worksheetExists(cell) Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = cell
    Else
        Sheets(cell).Cells.Clear
    End If

    Sheets(cell).Paste
    ...

 Next i
```

I go through the code until Shees(cells).Paste

In fact, how do I copy all items from one worksheet to another one - if there exists a worksheet with that name then clear it out and then paste the contents into it from scratch.

thanks in advance...

Comment: What runtime error do you get and on what line does the error occur.

Answer (score 0):

...untested, but the other actions probably forfeit the selection. Try putting the .Copy-line directly before the .Paste-line, and then give the starting cell, like `Sheets(cell).Range("A1").Paste` or rather directly

```
Sheets("skeleton").Range("A1:S21").Copy Sheets(cell).Range("A1")
```

Comment: Please mark this as the answer if it worked as to help other users

Answer (score 0):

Including your question re copying entire worksheets; you could probably copy the whole sheet and paste into the new one rather than having to clear the cells first, alternatively you could delete a sheet if it exists and then copy the required sheet and rename it:

```
Dim cell As String

For i = 2 To cat_lastRow
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    cell = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value

    ' Turn off alert that you are deleting sheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts False
    ' Resume next on error if the sheet does not already exist
    On Error Resume Next
    Sheets(cell).Delete
    ' Rest your error handle
    On Error GoTo 0
    Sheets("skeleton").Copy after:=Sheets("Sheet3")
    ActiveSheet.Name = cell
 Next i
```

Make sure you put Application.DisplayAlerts True at the end of your code and you may need to change your on error as well once you have deleted the sheet.